# How to change the URL without change the FTP

Tags: redirect

So, i am facing a damn big problem...
I need to chage some URL's from a client, but i wanna know how to make that without have to change the files locations and pastes....

For Example:
 Today i have this page: https://viahavok.com.br/cursos/3D/
 The files of this page are located at public_html/cursos/3D/index.php
 . I need to change the url to https://viahavok.com.br/cursos/Printing-3D and i wanna do it without have to create a folder named Printing-3D and transfer the files.... How i do it?

Comment: Use rewrite rules on the server that translate back to the old location.

Comment: And how i do that?

Comment: Read a tutorial on webserver configuration, it should explain how to do rewrites.